# django-imagekit get model attribute

Tags: django, django-models, django-imagekit

I have the following model:

```
class PropertyPhoto(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey('Property')
    photo_show = ProcessedImageField(upload_to=get_web_watermark,
                                  processors=[Watermark()],                                     
                                  options={'quality': 95})
```

and custom Watermark class:

```
class Watermark(object):    

    def process(self, image):
        try:
            this_property = Property.objects.get(pk=*self.property.id*)
        except Property.DoesNotExist:
            print "error"
```

How do I access my model attribute "property" from inside Watermark class?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom spec that gets the information you need from the model and passes it to your processor. The docs show [an example](https://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#specs-that-change):

```
from django.db import models
from imagekit import ImageSpec, register
from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill
from imagekit.utils import get_field_info

class AvatarThumbnail(ImageSpec):
    format = 'JPEG'
    options = {'quality': 60}

    @property
    def processors(self):
        model, field_name = get_field_info(self.source)
        return [ResizeToFill(model.thumbnail_width, thumbnail.avatar_height)]

register.generator('myapp:profile:avatar_thumbnail', AvatarThumbnail)

class Profile(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars')
    avatar_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='avatar',
                                      id='myapp:profile:avatar_thumbnail')
    thumbnail_width = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    thumbnail_height = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Note that you can pass the spec directly to the `ImageSpecField` constructor (using the `spec` kwarg) instead of registering it with an id (and using the `id` kwarg) as shown above.