# (Django) How to transfer value from field to the custom ImageKit processor inside the model?

Tags: django, django-imagekit

I use [Django ImageKit](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit) to process/crop uploaded photos. I added my own custom processor to add text to the photo (like watermark):

```
# ./example/processors.py

from django.conf import settings
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

_default_font = ImageFont.truetype(settings.TEXT_OVERLAY_FONT_REGULAR, 24)


def add_text_overlay(image, text, font=_default_font):
    rgba_image = image.convert('RGBA')
    text_overlay = Image.new('RGBA', rgba_image.size, (255, 255, 255, 0))

    image_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(text_overlay)
    text_size_x, text_size_y = image_draw.textsize(text, font=font)
    text_xy = ((rgba_image.size[0] / 2) - (text_size_x / 2), (rgba_image.size[1] / 2) - (text_size_y / 2))

    image_draw.text(text_xy, text, font=font, fill=(255, 255, 255, 255))
    image_with_text_overlay = Image.alpha_composite(rgba_image, text_overlay)

    return image_with_text_overlay


class TextOverlayProcessor(object):
    def __init__(self, text='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'):
        """
        :param text: The overlay text, string.

        """
        self.text = text

    def process(self, img):
        return add_text_overlay(image=img, text=self.text)
```

But how to transfer value from field to the custom ImageKit processor inside the model? Something like this:

```
# ./example/models.py

from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill
from .processors import TextOverlayProcessor


class Example(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField('Description', ...)
    image = models.ImageField('Picture', default=None)

    image_800x800 = ImageSpecField(
        source='image',
        processors=[
            ResizeToFill(800, 800), 
            TextOverlayProcessor(text=self.description) # but `self` is wrong and raise error
        ], 
        format='JPEG',
        options={'quality': 100}
    )
    ...
```

I will be glad to explanatory comments and/or use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/27914831/6543526

From official [docs](https://django-imagekit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#specs-that-change):

> Often, when using an ImageSpecField, you may want the spec to vary
>   based on properties of a model. (For example, you might want to store
>   image dimensions on the model and then use them to generate your
>   thumbnail.) Now that we know how to access the source image from our
>   spec, it’s a simple matter to extract its model and use it to create
>   our processors list. In fact, ImageKit includes a utility for getting
>   this information.